# SQL: prevent update if field value below certain value

Tags: sql, triggers, constraints, h2, flyway

I would like to add a constraint to my table:

```
create table asset (
   id number(19,0) not null,
    name varchar2(255 char),
    description varchar2(255 char),
    type varchar2(255 char),
    height number(10,0),
    width number(10,0),
    bytes blob,
    primary key (id)
);
```

after have stored on it Assets with ID from 0 to 8:

```
ALTER TABLE ASSET ADD CONSTRAINT check_if_id_bigger_than_eight CHECK (ID > 8)
```

to avoid further modifications of rows with IDs from 0 to 8, unfortunately the above is not working because its not allowed to have data which violate the constraints, is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: You need to do this via a trigger.  The constraint is on values within a row.  It is not a yes/no flag on whether values can be updated.

Comment: H2 only supports triggers written in Java. You can't define them in SQL

Answer (score 0):

This trigger may work (sql server syntax)

```
create trigger TR_8 
on asset
after insert, update

as
if exists(
 select * -- checks if new or modified datum has id between 0 and 8
 from inserted 
 where inserted.id between 0 and 8
)
begin
 RAISERROR ('Ids between 0 and 8 must stay untouched', 16, 10); --if so, rollback the transaction giving an error
 rollback transaction
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually not working on H2, do you know how to correct the syntax for H2?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used H2. Anyway I suggest you to add H2 tag to your question